# How to use variable in ajax html(data) function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I need to be able to use a variable in my ajax function when setting the "xxx.html(data)".  Like this:

```
function getChildren(tsk) { 
    var taskId = "'#" + tsk +"'";

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "kids1.jsp",
        success: function(data){
            alert("tsk="+tsk);
            //$("#0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1").html(data);
            $(taskId).html(data);
          }     
    }); 
}
```

It works when i explicitly put the actual id in (below).

```
    //$("#0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1").html(data);
```

But when I substitute w/the actual ID that's passed in, it doesn't work. 
I have tried this myriad ways.  Nothing seems to work.

I'm doing this for multiple branches in a tree.  So I need to be able to pass in the ID value.

And I'm very new to ajax and jQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(taskId);` inside your success function outputs what?

Comment: nvm change `var taskId = "'#" + tsk +"'";` to `var taskId = '#'.concat(tsk);`

Comment: bassxzero - THANK YOU!!!!! that has done it!! although, I've now found another issue, but this worked!! thanks so much!! :) :)

Comment: I made it an answer.

Comment: `var taskId = "#" + tsk;` why concat? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance

Answer (score 0):

Change `var taskId = "'#" + tsk +"'";` to `var taskId = "#"+tsk;`

What you have expands to `"'#someid'"`.
What jQuery wants is `'#someid'`.

Comment: [It is strongly recommended that assignment operators (+, +=) are used instead of the concat() method. See this performance test.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance)

Comment: @mplungjan I strongly recommend the `concat()` method because it converts each item to a string before concatenating, which prevents unexpected things from happening with unary operators. Also, I really don't think using concat a couple of times on one page is going to destroy the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
var taskId = '#' + controlid
```